# Draw boundaries using groups and order for each region gg_map Rgooglemaps

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to plot custom boundaries (dma's) into a google map.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

US <- get_map(location = c(-95.7129,37.0902),zoom = 3)
US_map <- ggmap(US)
```

then using the following CSV file with the coordinates groups and order

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xv192k5401np4r/DMAs%20coordinates%20sample.csv?dl=0

Then I can plot the coordinates using dots:

```
smpl <- read.csv('DMAs coordinates sample.csv')
US_map + geom_point(data=smpl,aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude),size=0.01)
```

[image: US map for sample of 6 dma's]

But I would like to plot lines connected by these dots using the path from `point_order` and group each set of lines using `dma_boundary.UniqueID` I'm sure there's a way to do this. but I cannot find the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this,

Using `geom_path` for each group represented by `dma_boundaty.UniqueID`

As the data is already sorted by `sub_polygon_id` and `point_order` we use geom_path to use the order set in data. Then,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(ggmap)

dma_boundaty <- data.table(read.csv('.../path')

    US <- get_map(location = c(-95.7129,37.0902),zoom = 3)
    US_map <- ggmap(US)
    dma_map <- US_map + lapply(0:205,function(i) {
                  geom_path(data=dma_boundary[dma_boundary.UniqueID == i,],aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude))})
```

[image]